# Substitute pattern multiple times in same line

Tags: regex, sed, preg-replace, replace

I'm trying to come up with a regex search/replace to encapsulate variables (eg; `$foo`) with braces (eg; `${foo}`). I came up with the following regex, but it's not working as intended:

```
s/"\([^"]*\)\$\([a-zA-Z0-9:]*\)\([^"]*\)"/"\1\${\2}\3"/g
```

However, I have some problems with this pattern. It will only do one pattern per quoted string. This is OK, since I can run the expression multiple times on the file but it doesn't handle variables already encapsulated in braces. It just puts a second set of braces on them.

My idea now is to strip `\2` of braces, but I don't think this will work since the pattern will still match and it will only perform 1 substitution per quoted string. I looked at backreference expression documentation but I'm not able to determine a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
sed -e ':loop' -e 's/"\([^"]*\)\$\([a-zA-Z0-9:]\{1,\}\)\([^"]*\)"/"\1\${\2}\3"/' -e 't loop'
```

This puts the search/replace into a loop so that it will repeatedly attempt the replacement on each line until no more replacements can be done.

This works because the current line being processed is only printed when there are no more commands to be run, `:loop` creates a label named `loop`, and `t loop` returns execution to the label `loop` only if there was a successful substitution.

As mentioned by potong in comments, this can have some strange behavior on lines with multiple quotes, here is an alternative that should work properly in these scenarios:

```
sed -e ':loop' -e 's/^\([^"]*\("[^"]*"[^"]*\)*\)"\([^"]*\)\$\([a-zA-Z0-9:]\{1,\}\)\([^"]*\)"/\1"\3\${\4}\5"/' -e 't loop'
```

Comment: This will only work if there are only one pair of `"`'s on a line i.e. data such as `a "b" $c "d"` will end up `a "b" ${c} "d"`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
echo 'a "$a" b $b "b $b b $b" $c c $c "$c c $c"' | 
sed 's/"\([^"]*\)"/"\n\1\n"/g;:a;s/\n\n//;ta;s/\n\$\([a-zA-Z0-9:]\+\)/${\1\}\n/;ta;s/\n\(.\)/\1\n/;ta'
a "${a}" b $b "b ${b} b ${b}" $c c $c "${c} c ${c}"
```

Comment: Good catch on the multiple quotes issue.